# Finding top K frequent words

Tags: c++, algorithm

I am trying to solve a question from Leetcode website - [Finding top K frequent words](https://leetcode.com/problems/top-k-frequent-words/description/).

> Given a non-empty list of words, return the k most frequent elements.
>   Your answer should be sorted by frequency from highest to lowest. If two words have the same frequency, then the word with the lower alphabetical order comes first.  E.g.:  if the input is: ["the", "day", "is", "sunny", "the", "the", "the", "sunny", "is", "is"], k = 4, then the output should be: ["the", "is", "sunny", "day"].

One of the upvoted solutions is like below:

```
class Solution {
public:
    vector<string> topKFrequent(vector<string>& words, int k) {
        unordered_map<string,int> dict;
        for(const string& s:words) dict[s]++;

        priority_queue<pair<string,int>, vector<pair<string,int>>, Comp> pq;
        for(const auto& pa:dict) {
            pq.push(pa);
            if(pq.size()>k) pq.pop();
        }    

        vector<string> result;
        while(!pq.empty()) {
            result.push_back(pq.top().first);
            pq.pop();
        }
        reverse(result.begin(),result.end());    
        return result;    
    }
private:
    struct Comp {
        Comp() {}
        ~Comp() {}
        bool operator()(const pair<string,int>& a, const pair<string,int>& b) {
            return a.second>b.second || (a.second==b.second && a.first<b.first);
        }
    };

};
```

I am trying to understand it better and have a few questions:

1. When `pq.size()>k`, we `pop()` - isn't this incorrect because in that case we are losing the highest frequency elements?  I think so because as per the comparator, the elements with the higher frequency (or alphabetically smaller in case of equal frequency) are inserted at the top in the priority queue.
2. In case of a priority queue, when we implement our own comparator, we have to pass a second parameter (denoting the Container to be used), but not required when we use the default comparator - why so?  I mean, can't a *default* Container type be deduced automatically depending upon the type of values that I would be storing (first parameter, in this case `pair<string, int>`)?
3. In case of `pq.push(pa);`, what exactly is the type of `pa`?  I am wondering because `pq` contains `vector<pair<string, int>>`, but the `dict` only contains `string` (mapped to their frequencies in `int`).  How does using an `auto` automatically map the `string` key to its `int` frequency for insertion into the priority queue?

Apologies for such long questions.  And thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You are not really taking out the ones with the highest frequency because the ordered is reversed into the priority queue. Infact there is a reverse call at the end to output the elements in the *right* order. Note that is it made clear in the documentation.

From [docs](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue)

> Note that the Compare parameter is defined such that it returns true
> if its first argument comes before its second argument in a weak
> ordering. But because the priority queue outputs largest elements
> first, the elements that "come before" are actually output last. That
> is, the front of the queue contains the "last" element according to
> the weak ordering imposed by Compare.

3. The type of `pa` is the  type specified in `unordered_map<string,int>::value_type` which is `std::pair<const string,int>`.
   Infact each element of a `unordered_map<K, V>::value_type`,  is a typedef for `std::pair<const K, V>` And since the `priority_queue` stores `std::pair<string,int>` there is not strange things appening.

Hope this helps.

Comment: just a side note: it's not `std::pair<string,int>`, but `std::pair<const string,int>` ;>

Comment: About (1) - the return statement is `return a.second>b.second || (a.second==b.second && a.first<b.first);`, so, isn't it sorted with the highest frequency elements at the top?  Could you please elaborate?  It would be very helpful for my understanding.

Comment: Okay, so by `last` you mean `a` (because it is better than `b`)?

Comment: Okay, got you.  Thank you! :)